Extracting and formatting data from auth.log file using Bash
I need to extract authorization data from the auth.log file. I also need to format this data so that it is easy to view. In my case, it is several columns: Date Time User Action IP.
I already have a part of the code, to be more precise, I can get the data for the last 3 hours, but I have problems with formatting.
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE="/var/log/auth.log"
OUTPUT_FILE="/home/phantaserrr/Script/auth_log_report.txt"

current_time=$(date +%s)
time_threshold=$((current_time - 3 * 3600))

time_threshold_formatted=$(date -d @$time_threshold +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

awk -v threshold="$time_threshold_formatted" '
    /polkitd|gdm-launch-environment/ {
        
        split($1, date, "T");
        split(date[1], ymd, "-");
        split($2, time, "+");

        user = $5;
        action = $0;
       
        if (match($0, /rhost=([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/, arr)) {
            ip = arr[1];
        } else {
            ip = "unknown";
        }

        if (action ~ /session opened/ || action ~ /session closed/ || action ~ /logged out/) {
            # Clean up action string
            sub(/\[.*\] /, "", action);
            print ymd[1] "-" ymd[2] "-" ymd[3], time[1], user, action, ip;
        }
    }
' "$LOG_FILE" > "$OUTPUT_FILE"

When I try to execute this script, I get the following errors
awk: line 11: syntax error at or near ,
awk: line 13: syntax error at or near else
awk: line 17: syntax error at or near if
awk: line 22: syntax error at or near }

Here is an example of a log file format
2024-08-03T16:31:12.232218+03:00 phantaserrr-VM gnome-keyring-daemon[2015]: The PKCS#11 component was already initialized
2024-08-03T16:31:12.233818+03:00 phantaserrr-VM gnome-keyring-daemon[2225]: discover_other_daemon: 1
2024-08-03T16:31:12.250473+03:00 phantaserrr-VM gnome-keyring-daemon[2227]: discover_other_daemon: 1
2024-08-03T16:31:12.250567+03:00 phantaserrr-VM gnome-keyring-daemon[2015]: The Secret Service was already initialized
2024-08-03T16:31:12.251861+03:00 phantaserrr-VM gnome-keyring-daemon[2230]: discover_other_daemon: 1
2024-08-03T16:31:16.130923+03:00 phantaserrr-VM polkitd[730]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:2 (system bus name :1.79 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
2024-08-03T16:31:17.631108+03:00 phantaserrr-VM gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm


My guess: you are using GNU awk specific features like the third match argument but your awk is not  GNU awk. What does awk --version print?

I have the following answer
mawk 1.3.4 20240123
Copyright 2008-2023,2024, Thomas E. Dickey
Copyright 1991-1996,2014, Michael D. Brennan

random-funcs:       arc4random_stir/arc4random
regex-funcs:        internal

compiled limits:
sprintf buffer      8192
maximum-integer     9223372036854775808


So, you should install GNU awk or limit yourself to what this mawk supports.

rhost= doesn't exist in the sample input you provided so that's bad sample input as we can't test a potential solution using it. In any question, always provide a [mcve] that includes sample input and the expected output from that input so we can copy/paste it to test with. See [ask].

The 3rd argument for match() is a GNU awk extension and you aren't using GNU awk but you don't need it for what you're doing. Just change this:
    if (match($0, /rhost=([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/, arr)) {
        ip = arr[1];

to this:
    if (match($0, /rhost=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)) {
        ip = substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)

for it to work in any POSIX awk.
Also, for conciseness, consider using ([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+ in the regexp instead of [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+, assuming your awk version supports regexp intervals like {3}.
